# Passing a structure to GLSL as Uniform

Tags: opengl, glsl

Is there a way to pass a custom structures as uniform to GLSL shader?
The OpenGL Cookbook shows a way to do it by using the function setUniform('stuff') but this method is not clear to me.

Comment: Use [Uniform Buffer Objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object). The **std140** layout is part of the OpenGL specification. Other layouts are possible, but this is the best place to start.

Comment: There is no `setUniform` function; that's why Google didn't help. If you're talking about [`glUniform`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glUniform), that's a real function used to [set uniform values](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_%28GLSL%29).